# Stripping Quotations from a List of Lists

Tags: python

I have written a short function as part of my program that strips the quotation marks (") from a list of lists. An example of the input data is:

```py
[['"foo"', '"Spam"', '123', '"Angry Badger"'],
 ['"dead"', '"Parrot"', '321', '987']]
```

The target result would be:

```py
[['foo', 'Spam', '123', 'Angry Badger'],
 ['dead', 'Parrot', '321', '987']]
```

This code I am using to parse this is:

```py
def quote_strip(input_file):

    for k1, v1 in enumerate(input_file):
        for k2, v2 in enumerate(v1):
            input_file[k1][k2] = v2.lstrip('"').rstrip('"')

    return input_file
```

This works fine, but I am pretty sure there is a way of making this a single line. I just always seem to mess up comprehensions when they have the `=` sign in them like this.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you've got to traverse a 2D array in Python, your code will be minimum 2 lines just for the traversal.

Comment: @RussJ Unless one were to use a list comprehension.

Comment: I agree with @Peilonrayz - it is easy enough to write `[x for i in file for x in i]`. It is just the `=` that is throwing me.

Comment: You just need `new_input_file = [ ... ]`

Comment: But if you do that with this case it will just add each `v2` item to that list in a single go. I want to maintain the shape of the original list, just with the `"` stripped out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just always seem to mess up comprehensions when they have the `=` sign in them like this.

I found the best way to think about comprehensions is instead think of comprehensions as `.append`s.

Lets change your inner loop to use `.append` instead.
We don't need to use `enumerate` as we'll be building a new list.

```py
def quote_strip(input_file):
    for k1, v1 in enumerate(input_file):
        inner_list = []
        for v2 in v1:
            inner_list.append(v2.lstrip('"').rstrip('"'))
        input_file[k1] = inner_list
    return input_file
```

We can now change the code to a comprehension.
I'll show you a pattern which we can just copy:

```py
my_list = []
for item in other_list:
    my_list.append(item + 1)
```

becomes:

```py
my_list = [
    item + 1
    for item in other_list
]
```

We just move whatever is in the `append(...)` to the top of the comprehension.
And move the for loop into the bottom of the list.

```py
def quote_strip(input_file):
    for k1, v1 in enumerate(input_file):
        inner_list = [
            v2.lstrip('"').rstrip('"')
            for v2 in v1
        ]
        input_file[k1] = inner_list
    return input_file
```

You should notice we can remove the need for assigning to the name `inner_list`.

```py
def quote_strip(input_file):
    for k1, v1 in enumerate(input_file):
        input_file[k1] = [
            v2.lstrip('"').rstrip('"')
            for v2 in v1
        ]
    return input_file
```

Now we can change the loop to use `.append` again.

```py
def quote_strip(input_file):
    output_list = []
    for v1 in input_file:
        output_list.append([
            v2.lstrip('"').rstrip('"')
            for v2 in v1
        ])
    return output_list
```

And again we can change the code to a list comprehension.

```py
def quote_strip(input_file):
    return [
        [
            v2.lstrip('"').rstrip('"')
            for v2 in v1
        ]
        for v1 in input_file
    ]
```

### Extra

> I am pretty sure there is a way of making this a single line

We can put the comprehension on one line but please *do not do so*.
How many lines of code you write is not important, how easy to read your code is.
Putting the comprehension on one line will make your code harder to read.

Comment: also see this SO example of nested list comprehensions, which may be handy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050243/1075247

Comment: Why is something like this hard to read?: `A = [[el.strip('"') for el in lst] for lst in A]`. Just curious

Comment: @joostblack When skim reading code, you can easily mistake the code as many things, so you need to actually read the code rather than skim read. Additionally coding with a focus on line count increases code density, notice how the OP's code is easier to skim read than many of the intermediary steps in my answer. Because the density of my code is more than the OP's. After reading hundreds of people's code I find the code which uses multi-line comprehensions easier to read. Hard to read code is the accumulation of all the little parts of code which stop you skim reading.

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert, and this is my first answer here. I'm sorry if it's not up to the mark.

What I understand from your question is that your goal is to make your function *shorter*. We'll start off iterating through parent list and mapping a lambda to each child. The lambda uses "str.strip()" which strips from both sides of a string.

```
def v1(in_l):
    for i, l in enumerate(in_l):
        in_l[i] = list(map(lambda x: x.strip('"'), l))
    return in_l
```

(Apologies if the variable names seem cryptic. I wanted to keep it as short as possible.)

This function could be shortened with a list comprehension:

```
def v2(in_l):
    return [list(map(lambda x: x.strip('"'), l)) for l in in_l]
```

And you could shorten it further with a lambda:

```
v3 = lambda in_l: [list(map(lambda x: x.strip('"'), l)) for l in in_l]
```

For readability, I would suggest going with the first one.
I ran `timeit.timeit` on each (including your own implementation), with the example list you provided as a test case and `number = 10000`.

All of them clocked in at around `0.015`. V1 and V2 seemed to fluctuate between `0.015` and `0.040`. V3 and your function remained around `0.015` consistently.

Comment: TLDR: Your function is fine. Shortening it provides no performance boost at all and sacrifices readability.